# HTTP Streaming for less than 1000 daily views

Tags: flash, performance, video, project-planning, http-streaming

I want to use http streaming (ie. partial download) to serve some videos (medium to HD quality) to public.

Idea is to have videos on server and offer some web page with embedded video player for user to watch selected video.

Planned capacity is about 250 to 1000 daily views, with low concurrency requirement (ie. not many users in parallel watching video).

I am thinking of complete solution like FLVPlayer or flowplayer to support this.

What bothers me are network bandwidth requirements (what is minimum kbps) mainly, and this video player performance when in "heavy" use.

For "heavy use" I consider adding possibility to stream many separate video files that I will add in back-end (via XML file or similar) and don't have experience with these players.

What are your advices on this solution?

Answer (score 0):

Even a fairly high quality video is only going to be ~1024-2048kbps.  With a 100Mbps FastEthernet connection (which is fairly low end these days), this will be plenty for 50-100 concurrent "streams".

If you are still concerned, then host the media files on something like Amazon [S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/) or [CloudFront](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/).  In that case your bandwidth is effectively unlimited.